# Microsoft VS code (insiders) using an unauthorized temp folder when installing extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am getting error messages when installing any extension on a remote Linux server. The remote server is very restricted and I don't have access except for my home folder. However, for some reason VSCode is trying to use a temp folder that I don't have access to. I am not sure how VSCode pciked up this folder. I can't find any reference to it anywhere in the configurations. I would like to know if there is a setting where I can change the temp folder. Below is the error:

[2022-07-29 12:22:07.755] [renderer1] [warning] Settings pattern "keyboard." doesn't match any settings
[2022-07-29 12:22:09.191] [renderer1] [warning] Settings pattern "keyboard." doesn't match any settings
[2022-07-29 12:22:09.514] [renderer1] [info] [attempt 1] Invoking resolveAuthority(ssh-remote)
[2022-07-29 12:22:18.740] [renderer1] [error] [Extension Host] (node:30808) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(Use Code - Insiders --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
[2022-07-29 12:22:18.762] [renderer1] [info] [attempt 1] resolveAuthority(ssh-remote) returned '127.0.0.1:57706' after 9248 ms
[2022-07-29 12:22:20.133] [renderer1] [warning] Settings pattern "keyboard." doesn't match any settings
[2022-07-29 12:22:21.184] [renderer1] [warning] Settings pattern "keyboard." doesn't match any settings
[2022-07-29 12:22:24.061] [renderer1] [warning] Settings pattern "keyboard." doesn't match any settings
[2022-07-29 12:22:59.505] [renderer1] [warning] Settings pattern "keyboard." doesn't match any settings
[2022-07-29 12:23:00.832] [renderer1] [info] Setting search error: Unexpected end of JSON input
[2022-07-29 12:23:00.858] [renderer1] [info] Setting search error: Unexpected end of JSON input
[2022-07-29 12:23:35.530] [renderer1] [error] Error while installing 'rogalmic.bash-debug' extension in the remote server. unable to get local issuer certificate
[2022-07-29 12:23:35.531] [renderer1] [info] Downloading the 'rogalmic.bash-debug' extension locally and install
[2022-07-29 12:23:36.173] [renderer1] [info] Downloaded extension: rogalmic.bash-debug /c:/Users/cn188966/AppData/Local/Temp/5460df4a-8335-4d43-86c5-bba02cebf85b
[2022-07-29 12:23:36.815] [renderer1] [error] ["NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/infa_shared/td/Temp/fwa/20282368-63b5-4cca-adab-e0dc48fb8ef6'"," at f (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:79:39323)"," at i.toFileSystemProviderError (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:82:44050)"," at i.toFileSystemProviderWriteError (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:82:44109)"," at i.open (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:82:39411)"]
[2022-07-29 12:23:36.829] [renderer1] [error] ["NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/infa_shared/td/Temp/fwa/20282368-63b5-4cca-adab-e0dc48fb8ef6'"," at f (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:79:39323)"," at i.toFileSystemProviderError (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:82:44050)"," at i.toFileSystemProviderWriteError (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:82:44109)"," at i.open (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:82:39411)"]
[2022-07-29 12:23:36.864] [renderer1] [error] Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/infa_shared/td/Temp/fwa/20282368-63b5-4cca-adab-e0dc48fb8ef6': NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/infa_shared/td/Temp/fwa/20282368-63b5-4cca-adab-e0dc48fb8ef6'
at f (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:79:39323)
at i.toFileSystemProviderError (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:82:44050)
at i.toFileSystemProviderWriteError (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:82:44109)
at i.open (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:82:39411)

[2022-07-29 12:27:51.400] [renderer1] [error] Error while installing 'yy0931.save-as-root' extension in the remote server. unable to get local issuer certificate
[2022-07-29 12:27:51.400] [renderer1] [info] Downloading the 'yy0931.save-as-root' extension locally and install
[2022-07-29 12:27:52.319] [renderer1] [info] Downloaded extension: yy0931.save-as-root /c:/Users/cn188966/AppData/Local/Temp/770b1f4a-f465-449f-946e-2fd002b4041a
[2022-07-29 12:27:52.954] [renderer1] [error] ["NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/infa_shared/td/Temp/fwa/90a51013-5550-438e-8c7a-2d9c9b8563cb'"," at f (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:79:39323)"," at i.toFileSystemProviderError (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:82:44050)"," at i.toFileSystemProviderWriteError (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:82:44109)"," at i.open (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:82:39411)"]
[2022-07-29 12:27:52.985] [renderer1] [error] ["NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/infa_shared/td/Temp/fwa/90a51013-5550-438e-8c7a-2d9c9b8563cb'"," at f (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:79:39323)"," at i.toFileSystemProviderError (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:82:44050)"," at i.toFileSystemProviderWriteError (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:82:44109)"," at i.open (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:82:39411)"]
[2022-07-29 12:27:53.024] [renderer1] [error] Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/infa_shared/td/Temp/fwa/90a51013-5550-438e-8c7a-2d9c9b8563cb': NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/infa_shared/td/Temp/fwa/90a51013-5550-438e-8c7a-2d9c9b8563cb'
at f (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:79:39323)
at i.toFileSystemProviderError (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:82:44050)
at i.toFileSystemProviderWriteError (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:82:44109)
at i.open (/home/cn188966/.vscode-server-insiders/bin/12b08be500f8a307f30e92cbc3ee39ba115eab69/out/vs/server/node/server.main.js:82:39411)

Answer (score 0):

I posted this in VS Code github group as well.  This was fixed in the latest insiders edition (released this week).

I have tested and I am able to install the extensions now.

Thanks,
Raj